# Bluetooth disabled on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, bluetooth

Bluetooth is disabled on ubuntu 14-04. Tried the all the suggested solutions in the forum nothing works.

Looks like some bug also is going on to fix it.

When the update will be available?

I need solution with executing a set of scripts without affecting the existing system. It should be either patch or some scripts to be executed and should surely fix the issue.

Just to run it and should work, including driver fix or whatever else.

Comment: Tried the solution with bluez, editing rc.local, bluetooth manager, etc., but nothing worked.

Comment: Hello, please attach your `lsusb`, `lspci -nn` and `rfkill list` output from your terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t)

Answer (score 0):

I opened a bug ticket on this here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1366854 might wanna say you have the same problem.

Comment: This is the primary reason why I dont use ubuntu